# Which NuGet package creates the web.config in your Views folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, app-config

My project is missing the `web.config` file from the `Views` folder.  Here are the steps I took to make the project.

- Created an empty MVC project and installed the packages listed below.
- Created a controller and view.  The view was created by right-clicking the action name and selecting 'Add View...' from the menu.
- Attempt to run the project, but got the error `CS0103: The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context`

I am getting this error because `web.config` is missing from my `Views` folder. Since the `web.config` contains a lot of version numbers, tokens, etc..., my question is:

1. Why wasn't this added when I installed the packages?
2. Did the packages create a template I can use to make the `web.config` file?

Packages I installed:

```
Antlr   3.4.1.9004
bootstrap   3.3.4
jQuery  1.9.1
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc    5.2.3
Microsoft.AspNet.Razor  3.2.3
Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimi...  1.1.3
Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages   3.2.3
Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure    1.0.0.0
Modernizr   2.6.2
Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.4
Ninject 3.2.2.0
Ninject.MVC5    3.2.1.0
Ninject.Web.Common  3.2.0.0
Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost  3.2.0.0
WebActivatorEx  2
WebGrease   1.5.2
```

Comment: Neither. It's created by the MVC Project template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should prob look like this, as said in the comments it's part of the project template and not a package

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

UPDATE

The above is the default config file from the Views folder, it is added to a new Web Project when it's created using Visual Studio 2013. It uses

- Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.2
- Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.2
- Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages 3.2.2

Comment: I would like to accept your answer but it doesn't explain how you got the configuration that you posted.  If someone sees this a year from now it will not be useful because they won't know if their version numbers are correct.  Update it and I'll accept it.