# Why I have error CS0103 ASP.NET MVC 4.0 The name ''model" does not exist in the current context in Visual Studio 2015 Community?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

When I open my Asp.net 4 Application in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition, I have this error

[image: error]
[image: Configuration web.config]
  [image: Code]

Comment: Without seeing any source code we have no chance to help you

Comment: the build is work , there is no problem with code.

Comment: Show us the source code of the page you are getting the error on.

Comment: When I open my  Asp.net 4 Application in Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition, I Have No Error.

Comment: I have Same Problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319189/the-name-viewbag-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-visual-studio-2015?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You Should Upgrade your project from MVC4 to MVC5
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2