# Razor references not resolved in MVC 5 views Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

My current development environment:

- Windows 7 Enterprise
- Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 2
- Resharper Ultimate 2016.1.2

Project Configuration:

- C# .Net 4.5
- MVC 5

I have looked through several threads, blogs for example [ViewBag does not exist in the current context - Visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319189/the-name-viewbag-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-visual-studio-2015)

But my *.cshtml page shows few errors relevant to Razor
[image: Screen Shot]

I have

- Cleaned the componentModelCache @ `C:\Users\your.name.here\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`
- updated the Views\web.config `System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.2.0`
- and every possible config update available through the forums & blogs

Still no result. But when I create a brand new project this error does not appear. Any clue?

FYI, Error or not the solution builds and runs without any drama.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your `~/Views/web.config` for the following settings.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      ...
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

This is required for Visual Studio to recognize the types in your razor views.

Also ,

a. Unload and reload the project from the solution

b. Clean the solution

c. Exit Visual Studio, delete .user file in the project folder.

d. Open the solution again and build

Comment: Thank you @ahsan the additional update that i had to do was in `~/web.config` update the below section
`<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
...
</appSettings>`