# ASP.NET MVC app on .NET 4 do not find ViewBag and model in view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I had Visual Studio 2017, Visual Studio 2019 and old project in .NET 4 (ASP.NET website). Everything works perfectly on Windows 10 64 bit the last build, then I uninstall VS 2017 today.

After I uninstalled Visual Studio 2017, I now get this error:

> Error CS0103  The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context
>   Error CS0103  The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

But when I check Visual Studio Installer I have already .NET Framework 4 and ASP.NET MVC 4 installed.

I have this in my `web.config` file:

```
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Am I missing an ASP.NET MVC 3 framework? But when I try to install I got this error:

[image]

Is there any solution?

---

**Update:**

I try this solution: [The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context - Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319189/the-name-viewbag-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-visual-studio-2015), but does not work for me

I got this error:
[image]

But when I check it in Visual Studio 2019 Installer, I had already installed
[image]

I also try to install Visual Studio 2017 back and VS 2015, but I had still the same error and is it not possible to install ASP MVC 3
**But when I run webapp in Visual Studio, webpage works fine**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The name 'ViewBag' does not exist in the current context - Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29319189/the-name-viewbag-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Why not use the latest MVC 5 anyway? The other versions are out of date now. Maybe VS2019 does not support them

Comment: Because this system is big and uses old Windows Server which supports only .NET 4

Answer (score 0):

Check your MVC framework version, you need to have MVC framework 4.0. You can try to install from this link https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Comment: I install it, but nothing change, I had still same Error

Answer (score -1):

I have no MVC 3 project. So this is just guessing.

The Visual Studio Installer for 2019 only shows support for MVC 4.
[image]

Maybe [this download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=1491) helps. If it is not what you already tried.

Comment: I try it this before and Setup gives me a message then **Update does not apply** for MVC 3 exe file and in VS Installer I already had installed ASP.MVC 4 and .NET Framework 4